# Communication Protocol of Polar Watches

Tags: cordova, bluetooth

I have implemented a Cordova bluetooth ble plugin to read the heart rate from Polar heart rate monitors.
I am not sure if the Polar watches, follow the Bluetooth LE communication the same way? 
so that I can get heart beat from them without using the Polar AccessLink APIs.

I have tried searching on their website and developer portal, but watches and the devices are in separate sections and there is no clarity.